# Send and manage event on service call

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, event-handling

I need some advise about an event managing.

I have a J2EE application. 
When people or other entity use one of my service, I would raise an event. 
The idea is that if I have an event modifying state of my database table X, I want a process to see that event and execute action implied.

Ex: An entity call a service that add a new User. So I want that processes that use User list know that a new user is added to go get the complete updated list.

But the idea is, if during the get of the complete updated list there is two other add new user event raised, I want my process to go get the complete updated list. Only one time, not twice.

Have you idea about how achieve that ?

For now, my idea is to create a thread, checking an event pool, and analyse it to see if there is the same event twice.

But I'm sure there is good practice about my problem.

Thank you for answers.